# Injecting Files To Template From Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, assets

I'm trying to figure out how I can with Anthony Male's asset library which is also used for PyroCMS to load certain assets only through controllers to my template.

I have a template that loads specific files and depending on the controller such as the login controller I'll need it to inject login.js file at the bottom of the footer that was it'll load at the end of the template.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/developers/tools/assets

Comment: Yes I have Did I miss something?

Comment: Near the top of the above link, under basic usage: Set the files in the controller using `Asset::js('myfile.js');`. Then echo them out in the view using `echo Asset::render_js();`

Comment: You should make this an answer so I can upvote it and check mark it.

Comment: Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the official documentation for Anthony Male's asset library, which can be found here: http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/developers/tools/assets

Javascript files can be added in your controller using the following, where myfile.js is the javascript file you want to include, and is located at assets/js/myfile.js.

```
// Will add assets/js/myfile
Asset::js('myfile.js');

// Will add assets/admin/js/myfile.js
Asset::js('admin::myfile.js');
```

By default, Asset will minify both of these files and combine them into a single file (which is written to assets/cache/.js). To include this file in your page, use the following in your view:

```
echo Asset::render_js();
```

Comment: Thank you. Same topic different question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638002/correctly-locating-asset-file-with-asset-library

Answer (score 1):

you ask for bottom of footer but my answer will be useful for you.

i'm using asset library but not yours just with similar and it's how i handle it;

in my controller;

```
/**
 * Global header variable for header view
 *
 * @var array
 * @access protected
 */
protected $header = array();

public function __construct() {
    // it returns like : <script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/assets/js/jquery-min.js"></script>
    $this->header["jses"][] = js("jquery-min.js");
    $this->header["jses"][] = js("jquery.autogrow-textarea.js");
}

public function index() {
    // some code here
    $this->load->view("header",$this->header);
    // other views
}
```

in my header view;

```
<?php foreach ( $jses as $js ) echo $js; ?>
```